# increasing Error.stackTraceLimit not working in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have tried various ways to change to Error.stackTraceLimit in chrome.

It defaults to 10, I would like say 100.

All the docs, and SO says this should work.

Did something change recently?  I seem to remember this working a few years ago.

This is what I have tried:

1. Setting Error.stackTrackLimit = 20 in the console
2. Setting it in head and body of the page in a JS script
3. setting it via the stack-trace-limit js flag

In the first 2 cases the value does change (i.e. it reads back out the same)

In the third case it does not seem to change anything